# Python Webscraping to Excel

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping

I am using the following python code to scrape a website. The issue which I can't resolve is it scrapes multiple events successfully but only sends the result of the first event to excel. All help greatly appreciated

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

      
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0',
       'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}
for race in range(1, 3):
    url = f"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2019-01-01/flemington/sectionaltimes/race-{race}.json?callback=sectionaltimes_callback"
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    json_obj = json.loads(r.text.split('sectionaltimes_callback(')[1].rsplit(')', 1)[0])
    print(json_obj)
    #df = pd.DataFrame(json_obj['Horses'])
    #writer = pd.ExcelWriter('horses.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    #df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    #writer.save()
    #print(df)
```

Comment: If you don't need macros, you should consider using CSV files. They are way easier to program.

Comment: Hi could you suggest the change to the code

Comment: Check out Python [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create an empty `df` and use `concat` method to append DataFrame from loop `df` will have concated data from the looped and convert to excel

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for race in range(1, 3):
    url = f"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2019-01-01/flemington/sectionaltimes/race-{race}.json?callback=sectionaltimes_callback"
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    json_obj = json.loads(r.text.split('sectionaltimes_callback(')[1].rsplit(')', 1)[0])
    main_df=pd.DataFrame(json_obj['Horses'])
    df=pd.concat([df,main_df])
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.to_excel("horses.xlsx")
```

Comment: Wow works brilliantly you are a star.

Comment: I have also noticed that the heading Sectionaltimes is a string of values which is all comma separated. I was going to split this in excel but was wondering can this also be displayed as separate fields

Comment: you need to take `df` with column name `SectionalTimes` to iterate list of values and create seprate columns and then merge to existing `df` so you will get desired output